# Language Service is not returning correct results for plural words

Tags: languageservice

If I queried Language Service with 'determining budgetary units' and 'determining budgetary unit' for both input Language Service is responding with different results

If I queried the Language Service with 'determining budgetary units' it returned enter image description here with confidence score 0.53 that is 53% If I queried the Language Service with 'determining budgetary unit' it returned enter image description here with confidence score 0.71 that is 71% Ideally for 'determining budgetary units' and 'determining budgetary unit' it should return same output How to handle above issue in Language Service